# Spree extension: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Trying to make spree extension (shipping calculator) using docs from official site.

spree extension my_calc, then added to my app Gemfile: `gem 'my_calc', :path => '../my_calc'`, then `bundle install`.

In `my_calc` dir I created `app/models/spree/calculator/shipping/my_calc.rb`

```
module Spree
    class MyCalc < Spree::ShippingCalculator
        preference ...

        def self.description
            ...
        end

        def compute_package(package)
            ...         
        end

        def available?(package)
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

Then I added the following to `config/initializers/spree.rb`

```
config = Rails.application.config
config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::MyCalc
```

But when i try to start rails server, i got an error:

```
.../config/initializers/spree.rb:23:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Spree::MyCalc (NameError)
```

Please help.

Comment: Almost forgot. Spree version 2-1-stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method provided by @Agis will probably work, but imho there's a better solution, just wait until everything gets initialized:

```
config = Rails.application.config
config.after_initialize do
  config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::MyCalc
end
```

According to your calc path you will probably get `Unable to autoload constant Spree::Calculator::Shipping::MyCalc` error because Rails will try to autoload such class due to file path. To resolve it change your class a little:

```
module Spree
  class Calculator::Shipping::MyCalc < ShippingCalculator
  (...)
```

Now everything should get loaded fine and as a bonus you will see your calc in admin page without adding anything more.

Comment: Error gone after i change config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::MyCalc to config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::Calculator::Shipping::MyCalc

Comment: And if someone founds it: better not to touch spree.rb in app, but add `initializer 'spree.register.calculators' do |app|
      app.config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::Calculator::Shipping::MyCalc
    end` to extension lib/my_calc/engine.rb

Answer (score 0):

Add the following somewhere above line 23 in `config/initializers/spree.rb`:

```
module Spree
  class MyCalc < Spree::ShippingCalculator
  end
end
```

Then restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: But this way i just define an empty class MyCalc. It will not add contents of my extension.

Comment: @ChipJuggler yes you define an empty class, but when the rest of your code loads (`models/` etc) it will be re-opened and the methods will be added.

Comment: I tried, but when i run rails c, and then mycalc = Spree::MyCalc.new, mycalc does not contain methods defined in extension (compute_package, available..)

Comment: Now it creates correct object (it has methods of ShippingCalculator), but it just generic object, for example mycalc.description print "Base Calculator". I think it still not loading my class.